# How to redirect a page after an event occurs in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

In my NodeJs application I want to render a file when a socket IO event occurs.

I am running a distinct socket.io server with python which does some calculation when an event occurs and triggers another return event to NodeJs side. However, redirect operation completes before the return event and page renders without the new data. What I actually want is to apply redirect with the new data 'x' after return event completes.

```
let x = []

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render('home', {'x' : x});
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  socket.emit('main event', 'data'); //trigger the main event
  res.redirect("/");
})

socket.on('return event', (data) => { //this is the return event
  x = data.x;
  // I want render to happen after this line
});
```

Is there any way that I can do the render operation not in express events and maybe in socket.io callback or maybe a blocking call that waits the event to complete?

Comment: Hi, you can for exemple execute a promise in your main action, and only render the view after it's complete....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers. What I actually needed was to put the socket.on event into the app.post like this.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  socket.on('return event', (data) => {
    x = data.x;    
    res.redirect("/");
  });
  socket.emit('main event', 'data');
})
```

Promises was also a good suggestion and thank you for all your answers again

Answer (score 0):

Add `res.redirect` to acknowledgment callback in `socket.emit`.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  socket.emit('main event', 'data', function(err, msg) {
    if(err) throw new Error(err);

    res.redirect("/");
  });
});
```